# Why am i getting the following the following error when using keras subclassing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the subclassing API in keras and I am getting the following error when I try to build the model, and I cannot find anything about the issue on github. As a note I set training to false cause I plan to just upload weights I already have saved.

```py
class VggBlock(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(VggBlock,self).__init__()

        self.conv1=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')
        self.conv2=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')
        self.conv3=Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')
        self.conv4=Conv2D(filters=512,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')

        self.relu=Activation('relu')
        self.pool=MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2))

    def call(self,inputs,training=False):

        x=self.conv1(inputs)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.conv1(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.pool(x)

        x=self.conv2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.conv2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.pool(x)

        x=self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.pool(x)

        x=self.conv4(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.conv4(x)
        x=self.relu(x)

        x=self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.conv2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)

        return x
```

```
model = VggBlock()
model.build((1,224,224,3))
model.summary()
```

When I try to call model.summary() I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: You tried to call `count_params` on conv2d_22, but the layer isn't built. You can build it manually via: `conv2d_22.build(batch_input_shape)`.

Comment: i think you need to pass in keras inputs `keras.input`vectors and then summary will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so I did some changes.

```
import keras 
from keras import Model 
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Activation,MaxPooling2D

class VggBlock(Model):

    def __init__(self,inp_shape=(224,224,3)):
        super(VggBlock,self).__init__()

        self.conv1=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=inp_shape)
        self.conv2=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')
        self.conv3=Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')
        self.conv4=Conv2D(filters=512,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')

        self.relu=Activation('relu')
        self.pool=MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2))

    def get_new_layer(self,layer):
        return Conv2D(filters=layer.filters,kernel_size=layer.kernel_size,padding=layer.padding)


    def call(self,inputs,training=False):

        x=self.conv1(inputs)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv1)(x) #self.conv1(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.pool(x)

        x=self.conv2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv2)(x) #self.conv2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.pool(x)

        x=self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv3)(x) #self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv3)(x)#self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv3)(x)#self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.pool(x)

        x=self.conv4(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv4)(x)#self.conv4(x)
        x=self.relu(x)

        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv3)(x)#self.conv3(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_new_layer(self.conv2)(x)#self.conv2(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        print(x.shape)
        return x


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (None,None,128)


model = VggBlock(inp_shape=(224,224,32))
inp = keras.Input(shape=(224,224,32))
out = model(inp)
model.summary() #works
```

Check the model for other functions like train,save,compile etc. And that error you mentioned in the comment, is because you need to write your own function to `compute_output_shape` when subclassing models.

Comment: I think its because of the function that I wrote `get_new_layer`. I just wrote it quickly to test somethings. You have to make all the new layers you generate your class members so that they reflect in `model.summary()`.

Comment: Does `model.get_weights()` return a list with 24 numpy arrays?

Comment: Long story short, you just need to declare layers in your `init`, all of them, even those that are identical. So yeah lot of repetition of same lines of code. And then ensure you write ` compute_output_shape` function.

Comment: @DanielMöller not 24, but 8. And its exactly because i didnt make new generated layers as class members.

Comment: @ADA I think you should edit my code to change the lines wherever necessary to ensure `summary()` works perfectly so that future users are not confused.

Comment: Do you really have the constraint that you need to follow exactly this format of keras model subclassing ? Because you can make your classes in your own style, no need to inherit from `Model` and just return write a method similar to `call`that returns `keras.Model(inputs,x)`. This will make things way more easier and flexible. and no need to write `compute_output_shape` function too.

Comment: also you need to write `relu`layers again. everytime you want to use `relu` declare a new relu inside `init` and use this.

Comment: ok let me post another block of code to show what im trying to say

Answer (score 1):

> **Warning:** this model will not work because the input channels you are giving to the same convolution layer are different

It seems a bug in the framework. You build the model, all layers should be automatically built, but this is not happening.

So, I suggest you pass an input to the model (and then you will see the problem I mentioned before):

```
inputs = Input((224,224,3))
outputs = model(inputs)
model.summary()

#but it's better to do this with actual tensors, not with this dummy input
```

Comment: Not necessary, the build function is not working anyway.

Comment: I have no idea of what the problem is in this case. Maybe you should just use the functional API, it's more Keras-like and works perfectly.

Comment: Are you using healthy versions? This bug you got is really strange. Maybe you're mixing `keras` and `tf.keras`?

Comment: Now this is perfectly ok, it's the first thing I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I found out something. When you write the line `self.conv1`  2nd time in the `call`method, it throws an error. Because `conv1` is your first input layer and its shape is fixed. When the  output of relu goes into 3rd line i.e. self.conv1 , this output is of different shape, it will be of the shape `(224,224,64)` while its expecting `(224,224,3)`. you have to declare another layer identical to conv1.

Answer (score 1):

```
import keras 
from keras import Model 
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Activation,MaxPooling2D

class VggBlock:

    def __init__(self,inp_shape=(224,224,3),trainable=False):
        #super(VggBlock,self).__init__()
        # write whatever you want here... 
        # also no need to write these layers too, just use the functions get_CONV...
        # you can just store parameters here you would want for each layer...according to you

        self.conv1=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=inp_shape,trainable=trainable)
        self.conv1_dup = Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',trainable=trainable)
        self.conv2=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',trainable=trainable)
        self.conv3=Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',trainable=trainable)
        self.conv4=Conv2D(filters=512,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',trainable=trainable)

        self.relu=Activation('relu')
        self.pool=MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2))


    def get_CONV(self,layer,name):
        return Conv2D(filters=layer.filters,kernel_size=layer.kernel_size,padding=layer.padding,trainable=False,
                     name=name)

    def get_model(self,inputs,training=False):

        x=self.conv1(inputs)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.get_CONV(self.conv1,name='conv1_duplicate')(x) #self.conv1(x)
        x=self.relu(x)
        x=self.pool(x)
        .
        .
        .
        #same as before 
        return keras.Model(inputs,x) #this is a keras Model object and it has all the functions you need.

vggClass = VggBlock(inp_shape=(224,224,32))
inp = keras.Input(shape=(224,224,32))

m = vggClass.get_model(inp) 
m.summary() #works
```

Comment: no, notice that my class does not inherit from `keras.Model`. Its just my own class which does not really follow model subclassing template from keras but still achieves all its functions because of the `keras.Model` object I am returning.